Expo React Native Android Emulator Can't Connect to Express Backend
I'm building a React Native frontend with Expo (managed workflow) and an Express backend running locally. My app works fine on the web version (using expo start --web), but when I test on the Android emulator, the frontend can't connect to the backend. I’ve tried several things, but nothing seems to work.
What I’ve Tried

Changed the API URL in .env.development:

API_URL=http://10.0.2.2:3000 (for Android emulator)
API_URL=http://192.xxx.x.x:3000 (my local IP address)
API_URL=http://localhost:3000


Updated app.json to allow cleartext traffic:
"expo": {
  "android": {
    "usesCleartextTraffic": true
  }
}



Confirmed backend is running:

Accessing http://localhost:3000 in my browser works fine.
Disabled firewall/antivirus to ensure they aren't blocking requests.


Tested API URL in Postman using my local IP, and it works.


Relevant code for reference:
.env.development:
#API_URL for web
#API_URL=http://localhost:3000

#API_URL for android
API_URL=http://10.0.2.2:3000

Example frontend api call:
auth.ts:
export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  console.log("API_URL", API_URL);
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.error);
  }
  return data;
};

I have a basic cors policy that should not effect this I do not think:
// CORS configuration to allow requests from the frontend
const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies, headers)
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Handle preflight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

Please let me know if other information is needed.

Do you get some error? Make sure IPv6 is enabled on the machine doing the emulation, even if you're not using IPv6. I found disabling it breaks Android emulator in weird ways. Please try to provide some more details about exactly what you're experiencing.

Could you log the response.request?

In one of Simon's videos, he says changing the url to http://10.0.2.2:<port> fixes the problem. Could you be overlooking something?

I do not know why but this didn't work for me either. I completely uninstalled android studio, redownloaded it, ensured every part of the emulator sdk was updated and reran it and it started working finally.


Your environment variables within your .env.development should start by EXPO_PUBLIC_, so in your case EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL


The Expo CLI will automatically load environment variables with an EXPO_PUBLIC_ prefix from .env files for use within your JavaScript code whenever you use the Expo CLI, such as when running npx expo start to start your app in local development mode.

Environment variables in Expo

(In development) The IP address of your backend should be the IP of your own computer, where it's being host. So in your case http://192.168.x.x:3000

Not the IP of your emulator, nor localhost/127.0.0.1. Because the emulator is like another device itself, it'd try to reach itself this way



